# Failed to load plugin Tinymce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

Suddenly my TinyMCE classic editor shows this error:

Failed to load plugin url: https://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/pt.js

I’ve switched off plugins one by one, nothing

I’ve reinstalled WordPress core files, nothing

But when i switch from my theme to a default one, it works… But how a theme can affect this plugin?

The problem occurred after upgrading Wordpress to 4.8.

Is there any way to understand where it comes from?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the theme use a heavy backend editor like Divi or Themify or some such? Sometimes they have editors that can break some of WP's core functionality

Comment: Does the file wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/pt.js exist?
Do you have any errors in the log?

Comment: Thanks a lot, can mark this as solved: it was a functions.php script related issue, removed that now it works!
Thanks